# No hard coding in where clause in oracle

Tags: oracle

[I have created a table as shown in figure

```
   CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (CAL_YEAR VARCHAR2(4), NAME VARCHAR2(1))

   INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(‘2020’, ’A’)
   INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(‘2020’, ’B’)
   INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(‘2020’, ’C’)
   INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(‘2020’, ’D’)
   INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(‘2021’, ’E’)
   INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(‘2021’, ’F’)
```

Let us assume I am querying the statement in this year like

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE CAL_YEAR= TO_CHAR((SYSDATE),'YYYY');
```

so I get present year values.

What I need is if the present year data not present in the table then I need to use previous year data i.e. 2020 data...How can I do this in the where clause itself][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYtXo.png)

Comment: Using parameters?

Comment: Please post the expected result for your sample data

Comment: I have taken a sample example...If I don't have current year data then I want to use previous year i.e. 2020 data (I don't want hard coding)...In the pic, there is a present year data..If I run the select statement in next year i.e. 2022 and I don't have 2022 data so we need to use previous year data i.e. 2021 data...So I am asking the query...Can't we do without parameters.

Comment: Why do you store numbers as string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show the previous year, if no row for the current year exists? Simply select all years until now, order by year, take the last one.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE cal_year <= EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)
ORDER BY cal_year DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get the maximum year that is less than or equal the year you query for in a subquery.

```
SELECT *
       FROM table1
       WHERE cal_year = (SELECT max(cal_year)
                                FROM table1
                                WHERE cal_year <= 2020);
```

Answer (score 0):

Optionally (if you're on a database version which doesn't support `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES` Thorsten suggested):

with year 2021 in the table:

```
SQL> select * from table1
  2  where cal_year = case when (select max(1) from table1
  3                              where exists (select null from table1
  4                                            where cal_year = to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy')
  5                                           )
  6                             ) = 1 then to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy')
  7                        else to_char(add_months(sysdate, -12), 'yyyy')
  8                   end;

CAL_ N
---- -
2021 E
2021 F
```

Without this year:

```
SQL> delete from table1 where cal_year = 2021;

2 rows deleted.

SQL>
SQL> select * from table1
  2  where cal_year = case when (select max(1) from table1
  3                              where exists (select null from table1
  4                                            where cal_year = to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy')
  5                                           )
  6                             ) = 1 then to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy')
  7                        else to_char(add_months(sysdate, -12), 'yyyy')
  8                   end;

CAL_ N
---- -
2020 A
2020 B
2020 C
2020 D

SQL>
```

What does it do?

- lines #2 - 5: `SELECT`* (within `CASE`) returns `1` if `EXISTS` says that there's at least one row whose `CAL_YEAR = this year`

  - if that's so (i.e. `1` has been returned), then `CAL_YEAR` is compared to *this year* (`to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy')`)
  - otherwise, if `SELECT` returns something else (most probably NULL), `CAL_YEAR` is compared to previous year (that's what `to_char(add_months(sysdate, -12), 'yyyy')` does - subtracts 12 months from today's date and extracts year from it)

Comment: Can you explain the query step by step

Comment: I did, by editing the answer. Have a look, please.